# Debounce and throttle tasks using Swift Concurrency

Tags: swift, concurrency

There are many debouncer and throttle implementations created using `Grand Central Dispatch`, and even one built into `Combine`. I wanted to create one using the new `Swift Concurrency` feature in Swift 5.5+.

Below is what I put together with [help from others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69787568):

```
actor Limiter {
    enum Policy {
        case throttle
        case debounce
    }

    private let policy: Policy
    private let duration: TimeInterval
    private var task: Task<Void, Never>?

    init(policy: Policy, duration: TimeInterval) {
        self.policy = policy
        self.duration = duration
    }

    nonisolated func callAsFunction(task: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        Task {
            switch policy {
            case .throttle:
                await throttle(task: task)
            case .debounce:
                await debounce(task: task)
            }
        }
    }

    private func throttle(task: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        guard self.task?.isCancelled ?? true else { return }

        Task {
            await task()
        }

        self.task = Task {
            try? await sleep()
            self.task?.cancel()
            self.task = nil
        }
    }

    private func debounce(task: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        self.task?.cancel()

        self.task = Task {
            do {
                try await sleep()
                guard !Task.isCancelled else { return }
                await task()
            } catch {
                return
            }
        }
    }

    private func sleep() async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(duration * 1_000_000_000))
    }
}
```

I created tests to go with it, but `testThrottler` and `testDebouncer` are failing randomly which means there's some race condition somewhere or my assumptions in the tests are incorrect:

```
final class LimiterTests: XCTestCase {
    func testThrottler() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure first task fired")
        let throttler = Limiter(policy: .throttle, duration: 1)
        var value = ""

        var fulfillmentCount = 0
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func sendToServer(_ input: String) {
            throttler {
                value += input

                // Then
                switch fulfillmentCount {
                case 0:
                    XCTAssertEqual(value, "h")
                case 1:
                    XCTAssertEqual(value, "hwor")
                default:
                    XCTFail()
                }

                promise.fulfill()
                fulfillmentCount += 1
            }
        }

        // When
        sendToServer("h")
        sendToServer("e")
        sendToServer("l")
        sendToServer("l")
        sendToServer("o")

        await sleep(2)

        sendToServer("wor")
        sendToServer("ld")

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    func testDebouncer() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure last task fired")
        let limiter = Limiter(policy: .debounce, duration: 1)
        var value = ""

        var fulfillmentCount = 0
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func sendToServer(_ input: String) {
            limiter {
                value += input

                // Then
                switch fulfillmentCount {
                case 0:
                    XCTAssertEqual(value, "o")
                case 1:
                    XCTAssertEqual(value, "old")
                default:
                    XCTFail()
                }

                promise.fulfill()
                fulfillmentCount += 1
            }
        }

        // When
        sendToServer("h")
        sendToServer("e")
        sendToServer("l")
        sendToServer("l")
        sendToServer("o")

        await sleep(2)

        sendToServer("wor")
        sendToServer("ld")

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    func testThrottler2() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure throttle before duration")
        let throttler = Limiter(policy: .throttle, duration: 1)

        var end = Date.now + 1
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func test() {
            // Then
            XCTAssertLessThan(.now, end)
            promise.fulfill()
        }

        // When
        throttler(task: test)
        throttler(task: test)
        throttler(task: test)
        throttler(task: test)
        throttler(task: test)

        await sleep(2)
        end = .now + 1

        throttler(task: test)
        throttler(task: test)
        throttler(task: test)

        await sleep(2)

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    func testDebouncer2() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure debounce after duration")
        let debouncer = Limiter(policy: .debounce, duration: 1)

        var end = Date.now + 1
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func test() {
            // Then
            XCTAssertGreaterThan(.now, end)
            promise.fulfill()
        }

        // When
        debouncer(task: test)
        debouncer(task: test)
        debouncer(task: test)
        debouncer(task: test)
        debouncer(task: test)

        await sleep(2)
        end = .now + 1

        debouncer(task: test)
        debouncer(task: test)
        debouncer(task: test)

        await sleep(2)

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    private func sleep(_ duration: TimeInterval) async {
        await Task.sleep(UInt64(duration * 1_000_000_000))
    }
}
```

I'm hoping for help in seeing anything I missed in the `Limiter` implementation, or maybe if there's a better way to do debounce and throttle with `Swift Concurrency`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the use of a `nonisolated` function to initiate an asynchronous update of an actor-isolated property. (I'm surprised the compiler even permits that.) Not only is it misleading, but actors also feature [reentrancy](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy), and you introduce all sorts of unintended races.

In the latter part of this answer, below, I offer my suggestions on what I would change in your implementation. But, nowadays, the right solution is to use the [`debounce`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Debounce.md) and [`throttle`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Throttle.md) from Apple’s [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms) library.

For example:

```swift
import AsyncAlgorithms

final class AsyncAlgorithmsTests: XCTestCase {

    // a stream of individual keystrokes with a pause after the first five characters

    func keystrokes() -> AsyncStream<String> {
        AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
            Task {
                continuation.yield("h")
                continuation.yield("e")
                continuation.yield("l")
                continuation.yield("l")
                continuation.yield("o")
                try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)
                continuation.yield(",")
                continuation.yield(" ")
                continuation.yield("w")
                continuation.yield("o")
                continuation.yield("r")
                continuation.yield("l")
                continuation.yield("d")
                continuation.finish()
            }
        }
    }

    // A stream of the individual keystrokes aggregated together as strings (as we
    // want to search the whole string, not for individual characters)
    //
    // e.g.
    //  h
    //  he
    //  hel
    //  hell
    //  hello
    //  ...
    //
    // As the `keystrokes` sequence has a pause after the fifth character, this will
    // also pause after “hello” and before “hello,”. We can use that pause to test
    // debouncing and throttling

    func strings() -> AsyncStream<String> {
        AsyncStream<String> { continuation in
            Task {
                var string = ""
                for await keystroke in keystrokes() {
                    string += keystroke
                    continuation.yield(string)
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
        }
    }

    func testDebounce() async throws {
        let debouncedSequence = strings().debounce(for: .seconds(1))

        // usually you'd just loop through the sequence with something like
        //
        // for await string in debouncedSequence {
        //     sendToServer(string)
        // }

        // but I'm just going to directly await the yielded values and test the resulting array

        let result: [String] = await debouncedSequence.reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
        XCTAssertEqual(result, ["hello", "hello, world"])
    }

    func testThrottle() async throws {
        let throttledSequence = strings().throttle(for: .seconds(1))

        let result: [String] = await throttledSequence.reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
        XCTAssertEqual(result, ["h", "hello,"])
    }
}

// MARK: - Task.sleep(seconds:)

extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {

    /// Suspends the current task for at least the given duration
    /// in seconds.
    ///
    /// If the task is canceled before the time ends,
    /// this function throws `CancellationError`.
    ///
    /// This function doesn't block the underlying thread.
    public static func sleep(seconds duration: TimeInterval) async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(duration * .nanosecondsPerSecond))
    }
}

// MARK: - TimeInterval

extension TimeInterval {
    static let nanosecondsPerSecond = TimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)
}
```

---

Given that you were soliciting a “code review”, if you really wanted to write your own “debounce” and “throttle” and did not want to use [Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms) for some reason, my previous answer, below, addresses some observations on your implementation:

---

You can add an actor-isolated function to `Limiter`:

```swift
func submit(task: @escaping () async -> Void) {
    switch policy {
    case .throttle: throttle(task: task)
    case .debounce: debounce(task: task)
    }
}
```

Note, I am not using `callAsFunction` as an actor-isolated function as it looks like (in Xcode 13.2.1, for me, at least) that this causes a segmentation fault in the compiler.

Anyway, you can then modify your tests to use the `submit` actor-isolated function, e.g.:

```swift
// test throttling as user enters “hello, world” into a text field

func testThrottler() async throws {
    // Given
    let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure first task fired")
    let throttler = Limiter(policy: .throttle, duration: 1)

    var fulfillmentCount = 0
    promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2
    var value = ""

    func accumulateAndSendToServer(_ input: String) async {
        value += input

        await throttler.submit { [value] in
            // Then
            switch fulfillmentCount {
            case 0:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "h")
            case 1:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "hello,")
            default: XCTFail()
            }

            promise.fulfill()
            fulfillmentCount += 1
        }
    }

    // When
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("h")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("e")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("o")

    try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)

    await accumulateAndSendToServer(",")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer(" ")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("w")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("o")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("r")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
    await accumulateAndSendToServer("d")

    wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
}
```

As an aside:

1. In `debounce`, the test for `isCancelled` is redundant. The `Task.sleep` will throw an error if the task was canceled.
2. As a matter of convention, Apple uses `operation` for the name of the closure parameters, presumably to avoid confusion with `Task` instances.
3. I would change the `Task` to be a `Task<Void, Error>?`. Then you can simplify `debounce` to:

   ```swift
   func debounce(operation: @escaping () async -> Void) {
       task?.cancel()

       task = Task {
           defer { task = nil }
           try await Task.sleep(seconds: duration)
           await operation()
       }
   }
   ```
4. When throttling network requests for user input, you generally want to throttle the network requests, but not the accumulation of the user input. So I have pulled the `value += input` out of the throttler/debouncer. I also use a capture list of `[value]` to make sure that we avoid race conditions between the accumulation of user input and the network requests.

---

FWIW, this is my rendition of `Limiter`:

```swift
actor Limiter {
    private let policy: Policy
    private let duration: TimeInterval
    private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

    init(policy: Policy, duration: TimeInterval) {
        self.policy = policy
        self.duration = duration
    }

    func submit(operation: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        switch policy {
        case .throttle: throttle(operation: operation)
        case .debounce: debounce(operation: operation)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Limiter.Policy

extension Limiter {
    enum Policy {
        case throttle
        case debounce
    }
}

// MARK: - Private utility methods

private extension Limiter {
    func throttle(operation: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        guard task == nil else { return }

        task = Task {
            defer { task = nil }
            try await Task.sleep(seconds: duration)
        }

        Task {
            await operation()
        }
    }

    func debounce(operation: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        task?.cancel()

        task = Task {
            defer { task = nil }
            try await Task.sleep(seconds: duration)
            await operation()
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses these extensions

```swift
// MARK: - Task.sleep(seconds:)

extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {

    /// Suspends the current task for at least the given duration
    /// in seconds.
    ///
    /// If the task is canceled before the time ends,
    /// this function throws `CancellationError`.
    ///
    /// This function doesn't block the underlying thread.
    public static func sleep(seconds duration: TimeInterval) async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(duration * .nanosecondsPerSecond))
    }
}

// MARK: - TimeInterval

extension TimeInterval {
    static let nanosecondsPerSecond = TimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)
}
```

And the following tests:

```swift
final class LimiterTests: XCTestCase {

    // test throttling as user enters “hello, world” into a text field

    func testThrottler() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure first task fired")
        let throttler = Limiter(policy: .throttle, duration: 1)

        var fulfillmentCount = 0
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2
        var value = ""

        func accumulateAndSendToServer(_ input: String) async {
            value += input

            await throttler.submit { [value] in
                // Then
                switch fulfillmentCount {
                case 0:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "h")
                case 1:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "hello,")
                default: XCTFail()
                }

                promise.fulfill()
                fulfillmentCount += 1
            }
        }

        // When
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("h")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("e")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("o")

        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)

        await accumulateAndSendToServer(",")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer(" ")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("w")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("o")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("r")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("d")

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    // test debouncing as user enters “hello, world” into a text field

    func testDebouncer() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure last task fired")
        let debouncer = Limiter(policy: .debounce, duration: 1)
        var value = ""

        var fulfillmentCount = 0
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func accumulateAndSendToServer(_ input: String) async {
            value += input

            await debouncer.submit { [value] in
                // Then
                switch fulfillmentCount {
                case 0:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "hello")
                case 1:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "hello, world")
                default: XCTFail()
                }

                promise.fulfill()
                fulfillmentCount += 1
            }
        }

        // When
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("h")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("e")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("o")

        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)

        await accumulateAndSendToServer(",")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer(" ")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("w")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("o")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("r")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("l")
        await accumulateAndSendToServer("d")

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    func testThrottler2() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure throttle before duration")
        let throttler = Limiter(policy: .throttle, duration: 1)

        var end = Date.now + 1
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func test() {
            // Then
            XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(.now, end)
            promise.fulfill()
        }

        // When
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)

        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)
        end = .now + 1

        await throttler.submit(operation: test)
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)
        await throttler.submit(operation: test)

        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }

    func testDebouncer2() async throws {
        // Given
        let promise = expectation(description: "Ensure debounce after duration")
        let debouncer = Limiter(policy: .debounce, duration: 1)

        var end = Date.now + 1
        promise.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        func test() {
            // Then
            XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(.now, end)
            promise.fulfill()
        }

        // When
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)

        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)
        end = .now + 1

        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)
        await debouncer.submit(operation: test)

        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 2)

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the review! Looks like bug reported for `callAsFunction` crash for actors: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15361, good catch. Regarding why `nonisolated` worked for my version is because I call `Task` inside so it becomes isolated again (I think?). But also doing it this way so the caller doesn't have to be in a concurrency/await state, anyone can call and forget it. Last thing, I still couldn't get the first 2 tests to pass in either of our versions (`testThrottler` and `testDebouncer`). I've struggled to understand if something is wrong with the limiter logic or the test itself.

Comment: I would advise against that that “use non-isolated function to initiate an asynchronous isolated asynchronous task” technique because not only is it very misleading, but actors also feature [reentrancy](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy), and you introduce all sorts of unintended races, which is why I excised the pattern from my answer above.

Comment: shouldn't that be `case 1:  XCTAssertEqual(value, "ld")` in `testDebouncer()` ?

Comment: @Martin - Because `sendToServer` was appending to `value`, and he never resets `value`, the final result of `"old"` is the final `"o"` of `"hello"` and the `"ld"` of `"world"`. This is, IMHO, a very counter-intuitive example (you generally want to debounce/throttle network requests, not the user input). I was attempting to mirror the test in the question as closely as possible. But I have revised my answer with a more intuitive handling of debouncing/throttling network requests but not user input.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much for the detailed explanation @Rob! That makes sense to me now.

Comment: @Rob: I tried your code snippet and with Swift 5.8 as per Xcode 14.3, the tests are failing. E.g.: `testDebouncer(): XCTAssertEqual failed: ("hel") is not equal to ("hello")`